# Eloquent paginate two relation merged

Tags: laravel, pagination, eloquent, relationship

I have two models : Task and Comment

In my user profil I want to display tasks and comments sort by created date.

For this I do :

```
$timeline_array = $customer->comments;
$timeline_array = $timeline_array->toBase()->merge($customer->tasks);

//sort timeline event
$timeline_array = $timeline_array->sortByDesc(function($timeline_event){
    return $timeline_event->created_at;
});
```

And I foreach my array in my view. It's work fine but if I have too much comments or tasks it's will be a big request so I want to add a paginator.

How can I do it ?

If I had a `$timeline_array->paginate(5);` at the end I get the error :

> Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate does not exist.

And I think it's not fixing my problem because I load all the comments and tasks before I paginate it.

Somebody have an idea/solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a solution  :

```
$timeline_array = $customer->comments;
$timeline_array = $timeline_array->toBase()->merge($customer->tasks);

//sort timeline event
$timeline_array = $timeline_array->sortByDesc(function($timeline_event){
  return $timeline_event->created_at;
});

$item_per_page = 10;
$timeline_array = new LengthAwarePaginator($timeline_array->forPage(Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(), $item_per_page), count($timeline_array), $item_per_page, Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(), [
  'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Paginate method only works on a query builder or an eloquent ,
someone has created a gist over here where you can use paginate over an array or collection :

> https://gist.github.com/vluzrmos/3ce756322702331fdf2bf414fea27bcb

Try using it like this :

```
$timeline_array = $customer->comments;
$timeline_array = $timeline_array->toBase()->merge($customer->tasks);

//sort timeline event
$timeline_array = $timeline_array->sortByDesc(function($timeline_event){
  return $timeline_event->created_at;
});

$timeline_array = $this->paginate($items);


public function paginate($items, $perPage = 15, $page = null, $options = [])
{
  $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
  $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
  return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), 
  $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
}
```

Or adding it as a Macro for collection in your App Service Provider for more better practice.

Comment: It was the correct way to do it but I need to use `LengthAwarePaginator` to make it work with my project but thanks !